# Best way to store targetable child records - ActiveRecord | Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What would be the best way to store the two child address records under a parent shipment record in the below JSON snippet using Rails' ActiveRecord?

Obviously the standard way to store child records is to configure the run-of-the-mill `has_many`-`belongs_to` relationship, but being that in this case the parent record "has two" child records, I can't see that as appropriate, plus, a `has_many`-`belongs_to` relationship wouldn't allow for targeting of one record over the other is the same way (i.e: `shipment.to_address` wouldn't work)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
{
  "id": "shp_vN9h7XLn",
  "to_address": {
    "id": "adr_zMlCRtmt",
    "name": "Dr. Joe Bloggs",
    "company": null,
    "street1": "323 Some Dr",
    "street2": null,
    "city": "Example City",
    "state": "XX",
    "zip": "00000",
    "country": "XX",
    "phone": "0000000000",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "created_at": "2013-04-22T05:39:56Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-04-22T05:39:56Z"
  },
  "from_address": {
    "id": "adr_VgoLT6Ex",
    "name": "Some Rep",
    "company": "Example Co.",
    "street1": "43 Example St",
    "street2": null,
    "city": "Example City",
    "state": "XX",
    "zip": "00000",
    "country": "XX",
    "phone": "0000000000",
    "email": "support@example.com",
    "created_at": "2013-04-22T05:39:57Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-04-22T05:39:57Z"
  },
  "tracking_code": null,
  "refund_status": null,
  "created_at": "2013-04-22T05:40:57Z",
  "updated_at": "2013-04-22T05:40:57Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your 2 addresses are different, one for `from_address`, and one for `to_address`

- A shipment **has one** `from_adress`
- A Shipment **has one** `to_adress`
- Both `from_address` and `to_address` are just Address.

So you can use Rails's STI (Single Table Inheritance) feature to solve this problem. I suppose you are familiar with STI, so just provide the final code

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :from_address, class_name: Address::FromAddress.name
  has_one :to_address, class_name: Address::ToAddress.name
  # Blah blah
end
```

To have become clear definition, you even can store multiple `to_adress` for one shipment without fear.

For further information, please read the [Rails's Guide # Single Table Inheritance](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance)